# ¿Cómo puedo hacer esta figura de forma recursiva?

Tags: java

La figura en cuestión que se me pide es esta:

```
*****
*  *
* *
**
*
```

(Un triángulo rectángulo al revés)

De forma iterativa ya lo he hecho y es fácil pero se me hace imposible pensar una forma recursiva para esto con JAVA. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

una cosa es que cumpla lo que te piden y otra es que tenga sentido. Sinceramente no me dió la gana de hacerte la tarea, pero no por ello dejaré de enseñarte algo.

Seguramente si entregas un programa como este obtengas una pésima calificación y quedes como un gilip*llas ante tus compañeros a pesar de que cumple con lo que te solicitan:

```
String[] figureToPrint = new String[]{
 "*****",
 "*  *",
 "* *",
 "**",
 "*"
};

void imprimirRecursivo(final int indice){
 if(indice<0 || indice >= figureToPrint ){
   return;
 }
 System.out.println(figureToPrint[indice]);
 imprimirRecursivo(indice+1);
}

// en algún lugar del main
// imprimirRecursivo(0);
```

Te explico la composición básica.
Estrictamente para que un método sea recursivo debe de solo una cosa y es llamarse a sí mismo

```
void imprimirRecursivo(int indice){
  imprimirRecursivo(indice-1);
}
```

La otra cosa inteligente para evitar que se coma toda la memoria es ponerle una condición de paro, por ello muchos consideran que es el segundo elemento obligatorio de una función recursiva.
Para nuestro caso se trata de poner los casos frontera, en vez de usar el viejo y confiable patrón de diseño bandera, flag o centinela como sea que lo conozcas, lo usaremos como condición de paro.
Ahora la condición de paro puede ir prácticamente en cualquier lado, pero una buena práctica a mi parecer cuando se desarrolla un método recursivo es usar el patrón de diseño early return, retorno anticipado o como lo conozcas.

El early return se trata de poner un muy horrible return para cortar la ejecución del programa, que si tu código del método es muy grande podría confundirte si no documentaste cuales son las posibles salidas de tu método.

La condición de nuesro early return será para nuestra implementación de juguete aquellos índices del arreglo que no podamos mostrar.

```
 if(indice<0 || indice >= figureToPrint ){
   return;
 }
```

Y la única desición restante es si lo recorres por índice ascendente o descendente, es decir

```
imprimirRecursivo(indice+1);
```

o

```
imprimirRecursivo(indice-1);
```

Para mostrar la figura tal como está lo pondremos simplemente ascendente y nos imprimirá fila por fila.

Truco intermedio por si ocupa alguien:

como verán el parámetro lo puse `final`, esto quiere decir que es una constante, de esa manera evitamos que se propague en cascada el cambio al valor del índice actual y que el comportamiento sea el que esperamos sin los famosos *side-effects* que la gente teme al hacer métodos recursivos.